Is there a FOSS (Free Open Source Software) OS or kernel with a similar structure to the openVMS or Windows NT kernel?
Is there a FOSS kernel or OS that is similar to openVMS or Windows NT kernel in design, functionality (structure of the kernel itself, more than one protection ring, etc.)?Also, is it at a practical level?

ReactOS immediately comes to mind, it's a full reimplementation of Windows, including the kernel and some basic applications.
